# How do I set UILabel in stackview to zero when It has no strings

Tags: swift, autolayout, uistackview

Hi I'm trying to use `AutoLayout`, StackView

I have 3 `UILabels` in StackView.

I want to implement that when `UILabel` has no Strings then set `UILable` height to zero. But It is not working.

I understood about contents hugging So I also try to set priority but It seems not working

Anyone knows about that?

[image]

[image]

**Update**

I solve this problem. It was really simple.

```
if cell.descriptionLabel.text!.isEmpty == true {
                cell.descriptionLabel.isHidden = true
            }
```

That's it!!

I hope you guys solve similar problem.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to hide the label when it is empty?

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. Before I had not uses stack view. added 3 UILables and make IBOulet of UILable's top constraints and checked isString or not programmatically. If has no string then I had changed UILable's top constraints. But I want implement via storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your height `NSLayoutconstrain` as `IBOutlet` and set it as `0` when there aren't any .text using Delegate to achieve that.

```
if yourLabel.text == ""{
   //here

}
```

Comment: thanks but I'm looking solutions with storyboard. Thanks a lot